# Raíz Quadrada em C

Tags: c

Segue o código:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>

    int main()
{

     double distancia;
     double x1, y1, x2, y2;

     scanf("%lf %lf ", &x1, &y1);
     scanf("%lf %lf ", &x2, &y2);

     distancia = sqrt (((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)));

     printf("%.4lf\n", distancia);
     return 0;
}
```

**Na hora de executar o programa, ao invés dele pedir 4 entradas como está escrito na entrada, ele pede 5 sendo que a quinta não interfere no valor final. O que é essa última entrada e por que isso ocorre?**

Comment: tente tirar os espaços do `scanf("%lf %lf ", &x2, &y2);`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tire os espaços do `scanf`:

```
scanf("%lf%lf", &x1, &y1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como foi dito acima, só tirar os espaços antes de fechar as aspas do *scanf*
Segue o código funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
     double distancia;
     double x1, y1, x2, y2;

     scanf("%lf %lf", &x1, &y1);
     scanf("%lf %lf", &x2, &y2);

     distancia = sqrt(((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)));

     printf("%.4lf\n", distancia);
     return 0;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```